# How to access property from grails query

Tags: grails

I have a domain class called Application as follows:

```
class Application {
    static hasOne = [resumption:Resumption, employee:Employee]
    //Employee employee 
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
    Integer amountOfDays
    String leaveRecommended
    String leaveNotRecommended
    Date supervisorDate

    String toString(){
        return "Application for ${employee.lastName}, ${employee.firstName}"
    }
}
```

In the ApplicationController I'm trying to write a query that is going to find all applications that match a particular employee id. I do so as follows:

```
def applicationlist(){

    if(!params.max){
        params.max = 10
    }

    def query
    def criteria = Application.createCriteria()
    def results

    query = { eq("employee_id", Long.parseLong("1")) }

    results = criteria.list(params, query)
    render(view:"employeeapplicationlist", model:[applicationlist:results])
}
```

Now I keep getting the error: "could not resolve property: employee_id"
I've checked the generated Application table in MySql, there is a column called employee_id with a value. The weird thing is I can access any other property (like amountOfDays), so what's the deal with employee_id? Why is it complaining that it cannot resolve the property? What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh well it looks like I'm still not fully adjusted to interfacing with the database on an Object level. For anyone else with this or a similar problem, here's the fix:

    query = { eq("employee.id", Long.parseLong("1")) }

Sine the Application Domain class has one Employee, then we just need to access the id field of that employee. Remember we're in the ApplicationController. Turns out I cannot answer my question so quickly. I'll post this as a comment in the event that I forget to come back a few hours later to make a proper post. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Associations in the criteria DSL are of the form

```
Application.withCriteria{
    employee{
       eq 'id', 1
    }
}
```

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria

But you could probably just do:

```
def employee = Employee.proxy(1)
Application.findAllByEmployee( employee )
```

This appears a few times in the Grails User Guide as 'querying associations'

Comment: Did you mean `load()` instead of `proxy`?

Answer (score 0):

Oh well it looks like I'm still not fully adjusted to interfacing with the database on an Object level. For anyone else with this or a similar problem, here's the fix:

```
query = { eq("employee.id", Long.parseLong("1")) }
```

Sine the Application Domain class has one Employee, then we just need to access the id field of that employee. Remember we're in the ApplicationController.